# PHP if OR multiple conditions get which is true

Tags: php, validation, if-statement

To avoid multiple `if` conditions or `loop`, is there a way to tell which condition is true: `empty($data1)` or `empty($data2)`?

```
// Validation
if ( empty($data1) || empty($data2) )  {
     echo 'Required data is missing';
}
```

Comment: first of all, you're missing the bracket closing the if statement

Comment: Hi @Shahbaz. If this any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answer-er and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Capture the results of each call to `empty()` to see which condition was true later in your code:

```
$data1IsEmpty = empty($data1);
$data2IsEmpty = empty($data2);
if ($data1IsEmpty || $data2IsEmpty)  {
    echo 'Required data is missing';
    if ($data1IsEmpty) {
        echo 'data1 is empty';
    }
    if ($data2IsEmpty) {
        echo 'data2 is empty';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i prefer to check per field if there is an empty or null value
for example :

```
if(empty($data1)){
echo "data1 is missing";
}
else if(empty($data2)){
    echo "data2 is missing";
}
else {
    //if all data is not null or empty
}
```

or you can make a function to check there is empty or not

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you are trying to validate a login form. Whatever the case,
@stephen's answer is your best bet. But if you are just checking random fields. Here's a workaround for any number of field checks

```
function isEmpty($field){
 return empty($field) ? "$field is required" : false;
}
$emptyInputs = [];
foreach($formInputs as $input){
 // $formInputs == data from form
  if($empty = isEmpty($input)){
     $emptyInputs[] = $empty;
  }
}  
return $emptyInputs;
```